# Would .. If and Will..If

Tags: grammar, conditionals, if

What is the difference between these two sentences:

1. Would it be OK if I asked for a raise?
2. Will it be OK if I ask for a raise? (if correct)

Comment: 2 implies that you are intending, or strongly likely, to ask. 1. Implies only that you are thinking about the possibility of asking.

Comment: Do you know the difference between 1st conditional and 2nd conditional? That's the answer to the question. There's no special idiomatic meaning to either sentence

Answer (score 1):

2 is how you would ask a co-worker their thoughts on you asking for a raise.  1 is how you might ask your boss.

Though actually, you would rarely want to use 2.  I can't really say why, I can only say that I find my Indian co-workers tend to use number 2 in most situations, and native English speakers tend to use number 1.  Either makes sense, but 1 is more native common.

Comment: It is OK to ask for a raise today. Will it be okay tomorrow? [to do so at another time.] Would it be okay tomorrow? [implies some doubt from the speaker]

Answer (score 0):

**I suggest saying either**

> *"Could I ask for a raise (AmE) / rise (BrE)?"*

**Or**

> *"Could I ask you for a raise (AmE) / rise (BrE)?"* ( especially in case you are speaking to the manager or, even, the chief executive );

**as it sounds *less wordy.***

I am not trying  to indicate there is something wrong with your sentences or that both are not grammatical or meaningful. Quite the contrary, they are those things.

My examples seem shorter and imply as much politeness and meaning as your first one which sounds less direct while the other is fine but practically expresses [more] certainty.

In short, I would use the one with *"would (also, more colloquial here)"* since the *"will"* sample sounds a bit off, but still correct.

> *Here are some stats from Ngrams:*
>
> [Will it be OK vs Would it be OK](https://ibb.co/Ks3b5mW)

I hope I provided and covered everything you need to know.